# GO : Define a type which is Map with 2 specifique Key

Tags: go, types

I want to define a type `Message` which is basically a `map[string]string` with 2 specific keys : `message` and `from`.

A `Message` should be :

```
map[string]string{"message": "Hello", "from": "Me"}
```

I defined a type Message :

```
type Message struct {
    message string,
    from string
}
```

Note : I need to convert this `Message` to json in order to send it though http request, that's why I "need" to use `map[string]string` => I finnaly found out that it's also possible to serialized struct as JSON objects

It is possible to defined a `type` which is a `map` with specific key with go ?
What would be the idiomatic solution to do this in `Go` ?

Comment: The idiomatic solution would be the struct you wrote above, but if there are good reasons to defy the idiom then a map[string]string should work, too.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to achieve... Do you basically want to lookup a value via one of two possible keys? Perhaps edit your question and elaborate a bit on the actual use case.

Comment: @adam-smith thx, it must be a map[string]string because to send it throw http with json format but I guess I can't write a toMap function for Message ? Thx

Comment: @blackgreen thx, but I don't need a map of Message, I need Message to a be a map of string with string as key

Comment: @nem0z a struct can be marshaled to JSON just as easily as a map. You cannot restrict what values are used in a map, only their type. Based on what you've described, the correct solution would be to use a struct.

Comment: @nem0z oh, that's the only problem? Let me write up an answer. Go structs support that but you have to tell it out to serialize.

Comment: @Adrian, Thx it answers all my questions !

Comment: If you know the "keys" or fields a particular set of data contains, why would you need said fields to be accessible using strings? This question has all the signs of an X-Y problem. You're asking to do Y, but the real question is X: Why do you think you need Y in the first place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As revealed in the comments on the question, the reason for preferring `map[string]string` is to preserve JSON encoding. However, structs can be serialized as JSON objects

```golang
import "json"

type Message struct {
    Message string `json:"message"`
    From    string `json:"from"`
}

myMessage := Message{Message: "foo", From: "bar"};
serialized, err := json.Marshal(myMessage);
if err != nil {
  // handle the error
}
```